# Rails app hanging while using PDFKit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdfkit

I've been using PDFKit to create pdfs and it seems the app hangs when I create a pdf while using `localhost` but not when I use `http://www.google.com` for instance.

This is my code:

`gem "pdfkit"`

And in my controller:

```
def generate_pdf(id)
    pdf = PDFKit.new("http://localhost:3000/quotes/550f313057694d5f43130000")
    directory = "#{Rails.root}/quotes/pdf"
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(directory) unless File.directory?(directory)
    path = File.join(directory, id)
    pdf.to_file("#{path}")
end
```

The above code does not work, but if I replace:

```
pdf = PDFKit.new("http://localhost:3000/quotes/550f313057694d5f43130000")
```

with

```
pdf = PDFKit.new("http://google.com")
```

It does work. Does anyone have any idea this is happening?

Comment: Seems like your server is single thread and it can handle only one request. So, the second request is blocking.

Comment: How could I fix this, you reckon?

Comment: Seems like you are using  Webrick, so just use "multi-thread/worker" servers like Thin, Puma, Unicorn, etc.

Comment: I did and have the same issue. App hangs while creating the pdf...

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK i am wondering if you found why this is happening and a workaround? i tried `Unicorn` but app still hangs!